# Unable to show image from Redux state in ReactNative

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux, react-native-image, react-image

My Reducer:

```
const initialState = {
  1: {
     id: '1',
     name: 'AryaStark',
     theimage: "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/3/39/Arya_Stark-Maisie_Williams.jpg"
    },
  2: {
     id: '2',
     name: 'SansaStark',
     theimage: "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/7/74/SophieTurnerasSansaStark.jpg"
    }
}
```

I am able to show rest of the content but not the image. My code:

```
const renDataNew = Object.keys(this.props.newData).map((key, idx) => {
   let data = this.props.newData[key]
    return (
      <View key={idx} style={styles.myStyle1}>
        <Text style={styles.myStyle2}>{data.id} - {data.name}</Text>
        <Image
        style={{width: '100%', height: 600}}
        source={{uri:{data.theimage}}} //<= Error here expecting a ,
        />
      </View>
```

If I use the url in `theimage` directly in the uri source of `Image`, it works. What am I doing wrong?

What is the proper way to show the image?
Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it should be:

```
<Image
  style={{width: '100%', height: 600}}
  source={{ uri: data.theimage }}
/>
```

You don't need extra `{}` around `data` object.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That actually worked. Why won't I need the curly braces around the `data.theimage`?

Comment: In example you are creating invalid object, it's syntax error. Second thing is that Image in [source](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image.html#source) prop accepts the image source as a String not Object.